# Rust program with Rust DLL panics when spawning a thread

Tags: dll, rust, dllimport

I'm trying to create a DLL using Rust which will have a constructor in Linux/entrypoint in Windows. For this question, only the Windows code is shown, but it also crashes on Linux.

I'm using this macro:

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
macro_rules! make_entrypoint {
    ($fn:expr) => {
        use winapi::shared::minwindef;
        use winapi::shared::minwindef::{BOOL, DWORD, HINSTANCE, LPVOID};
        use winapi::um::consoleapi::AllocConsole;
        #[no_mangle]
        #[allow(non_snake_case, unused_variables)]
        pub extern "system" fn DllMain(dll_module: HINSTANCE, call_reason: DWORD, reserved: LPVOID)-> BOOL {
            const DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: DWORD = 0;
            const DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: DWORD = 1;
            match call_reason {
                DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH => {
                    std::thread::spawn($fn);
                }
                DLL_PROCESS_DETACH | _ => ()
            }
            minwindef::TRUE
        }
    };
}
```

Calling it like:

```rust
pub fn injected() {
    println!("Called from windows!");
    loop {}
}
```

The binary program is:

```
use libloading;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        match libloading::Library::new("C:/<path>.dll") {
            Ok(_) => println!("ok!"),
            Err(err) => println!("{}", err),
        }
    }
    loop {}
}
```

The function is called in a new thread, prints `Called from windows!` and then crashes:

> Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x7ff8b23d25a3: User-mode data execution prevention (DEP) violation at location 0x7ff8b23d25a3

I think the problem is with `std::thread::spawn` because calling the function without a thread is ok.

It seems that because the thread is created in a child function, it is destroyed at the end of the parent function. What could be done to prevent it?

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices) from the Microsoft docs suggests you shouldn't create threads within `DllMain`.

Comment: Isn't the library you load immediately afterwards unloaded again, since you drop the returned value of `libloading::Library::new()`? This would certainly lead to a crash if your created thread is still running.

Comment: I put a thread.join at the end and the program didn't crash, so looks like it's because the thread is drop yes. Thanks @ssbssa

Comment: @kmdreko Yep i know, in my case i wanted to understand why spawning a thread made my app crash.